# How do you access azure data studio?

Tags: azure

I have been told to upgrade azure data studio.
When I search in windows search field the program doesn't show up.
However, when I go to my control panel and it is listed in programs and features.

How do you access azure data studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Azure Data Studio can be done in several ways depending on your operating system and how it was installed. If you're unable to find it using the Windows search field, you can try the following methods:

1. **Start Menu**:

- Navigate to the Start Menu on your Windows machine.
- Scroll through the list of installed applications or use the search bar within the Start Menu to find "Azure Data Studio," as shown below:

[image]

2. **Using command prompt:**

- Open the command prompt and use the `azuredatastudio` command to run Azure Data Studio. Execute the `azuredatastudio` command in the command prompt, as shown below:

[image]

It will open Azure Data Studio, as shown below:

[image]

If you are unable to launch Azure Data Studio using any of the above methods, you can try reinstalling it. Download the latest version from the official website and run the installer.